# How to initialize generic array?

Tags: java, arrays

This method is used to split array into chunks [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39788851/6891563). I want to make this method generic.

**Problem** is, I can not initialize array like this.

```
T[][] arrays = new T[chunks][];
```

complete method

```
 public <T> T[][] splitArray(T[] arrayToSplit, int chunkSize) {
        if (chunkSize <= 0) {
            return null;
        }
        int rest = arrayToSplit.length % chunkSize;
        int chunks = arrayToSplit.length / chunkSize + (rest > 0 ? 1 : 0);
        T[][] arrays = new T[chunks][];
        for (int i = 0; i < (rest > 0 ? chunks - 1 : chunks); i++) {
            arrays[i] = Arrays.copyOfRange(arrayToSplit, i * chunkSize, i * chunkSize + chunkSize);
        }
        if (rest > 0) {
            arrays[chunks - 1] = Arrays.copyOfRange(arrayToSplit, (chunks - 1) * chunkSize, (chunks - 1) * chunkSize + rest);
        }
        return arrays;
    }
```

What is correct way to initialize generic array?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot initialise arrays with a generic parameter. [That is a restriction on generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createObjects).

A workaround is to create an `Object[][]` and cast it to `T[][]`:

```
T[][] arrays = (T[][])new Object[chunks][];
```

Comment: Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'byte[]', required: 'T[]'

Comment: Why does this show error when invoking this method.

Comment: Can you please tell syntax to call this method also.

Comment: @Khemraj because your method is generic, you can't call it with primitive types: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#instantiate Use a `Byte[]` (note the capital letter).

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper because of this answer I check in ArrayList implementation it also more like this. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can't *create* a generic array, but you can *declare* a generic array.

```
T[] test = null; // works
T[] test2 = new T[10]; // fails
T[] test3 = (T[]) new Object[10]; // works
```

At the same time, you [should be careful with this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48068259/1059372)

Comment: is there any way to declare a generic array without the java compiler logging "uses unchecked or unsafe operations." when compiling the file that does this? `test3` causes that warning

Comment: @notacorn no, since you can not declare a generic array, you will _always_ have the cast to `T[]`, always.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make a generic array directly since type variable information is lost at runtime due to erasure.

However, in your case there is a workaround, since the output type of the method is just an array of type `arrayToSplit` and arrays in Java *do* have their type information available at runtime.

So instead of:

`T[][] arrays = new T[chunks][];`

you can do:

`T[][] arrays = (T[][])Array.newInstance(arrayToSplit.getClass(), chunks);`

Mixing arrays and generics can be confusing and error-prone though.  If possible, I would use the collections API where possible and use `List<T>` instead of arrays.

Guava even has a method that I think does exactly what you want:

[Lists.partition(List, int)](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition-java.util.List-int-)

> Returns consecutive sublists of a list, each of the same size (the final list may be smaller). For example, partitioning a list containing [a, b, c, d, e] with a partition size of 3 yields [[a, b, c], [d, e]] -- an outer list containing two inner lists of three and two elements, all in the original order.